# PUT request with json content-type

Tags: php, json, put

I have a `switch` based on `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` and something is going wrong in the `PUT` case.
The plausible way to read `PUT` is to use `php://input` and read it with `fopen` or `file_get_contents`.

The data that gets sent to PUT is of `Content-type: application/json`

Currently, this is the case I have got:

```
case "PUT":
        parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $putData);
        var_dump($putData);
        if(isset($_GET['id'])){
            putData($_GET['id'], $putData);
        } else {
            print json_encode(["message" => "Missing parameter `id`."]);
            http_response_code(400);
        }
        break;
```

The great thing is that my cURL request with key/value pairs work perfectly fine. The data gets filled and my `putData()` handles everything just fine.
The **problem** is that I need to accept JSON in this case, how do I go about?
My REST client throws an empty array when I `var_dump($putData)`.

Comment: parse_str isnt going to work with json.  Use json_decode instead.

Comment: When I just `json_decode` it throws an error claiming I am not sending a string but a resource?

Comment: Did you want to know how can you make a Ajax request from client side to your script by PUT method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using json_decode instead of parse_str

```
case "PUT":
        $rawInput = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $putData = json_decode($rawInput);
        if (is_null($putData)) {
            http_response_code(400);
            print json_encode(["message" => "Couldn't decode submission", "invalid_json_input" => $rawInput]);
        } else {
            if(isset($_GET['id'])){
                putData($_GET['id'], $putData);
            } else {
                http_response_code(400);
                print json_encode(["message" => "Missing parameter `id`."]);
            }
        }
        break;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, I noticed in my Postman app that it directly goes into 400 Bad Request. How do I send the right format in Postman?

Comment: I dont know, but maybe if you try doing a var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input")); It should return a json encoded string and might show where you are going wrong.  Actually I have made the error response a bit better now.  See edits.

Comment: It returns NULL directly in Postman, so how do I fill Postman correctly?
I tried putting key/value pairs in the request body, with Content-type application/json but that isn't the way to do it, apparently..

Comment: You need to choose "raw" then json from the dropdown.  Then you insert your json content in to the large text box.

Comment: I still get 400 Bad Request and nothing shown in the response

Comment: Can you use the updated code in my answer.  You should at least see "couldn't decode submission" now with the exact string which wasnt decodeable.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here, but if your REST client accepts JSON for this request, it will choke on `var_dump()` which outputs a string which isn't JSON right back onto the response. Try removing `var_dump()`

Also, I'm pretty sure you must call `http_response_code()` before any output is sent to the client.

Comment: I removed the `var_dump()` and used `json_decode()`, only thing returned is NULL at this moment, could that be correct?

Also, do I need to send a JSON string from the REST client **myself** to test this?

Comment: If you want to be able to read data which isn't JSON to the REST client, you should not tell the REST client to only parse JSON. Again, this is only a guess.